# Find whats the same in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

1)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 162 
    [1] => 163 
    [2] => 98 
    [3] => 13
)
```

2)

```
Array (
    [0] => 22
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 163
    [3] => 80
)
```

I want to find which values are the same in the these two arrays:

So that $thesame = 163 in this example

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try `array_intersect()` ...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php